# Рекурсивный cte

Tags: sql, sql-server, рекурсия

Здравствуйте.
У меня имеется такая таблица в БД со списком департаментов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мною был написан следующий код:

```
WITH tree (Id, Name, Level)
AS
(
    SELECT t.Id, t.Name, 0 AS Level
    FROM DepartmentsT AS t WHERE t.ParentId IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT d.Id, d.Name, Level+1
    FROM DepartmentsT AS d INNER JOIN tree ON tree.Id = d.ParentId
)

SELECT * FROM tree
```

В итоге я получаю следующий вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно вопрос - Как сделать так, чтобы записи выводились "иерархично", т.е. "дети" выводились под своим родителем, а не так как сейчас, что оно отсортировано по уровням вложенности. Простой `ORDER BY` проблему естественно не решает.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по всему у вас поле Id это символьная строка фиксированной длины. Если так, то можно сделать следующим образом:

```
WITH tree (Id, Name, Level, path)
AS
(
    SELECT t.Id, t.Name, 0 AS Level, cast(t.Id as varchar(max)) path
    FROM DepartmentsT AS t WHERE t.ParentId IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT d.Id, d.Name, Level+1, tree.path+'/'+d.Id
    FROM DepartmentsT AS d INNER JOIN tree ON tree.Id = d.ParentId
)

SELECT * FROM tree
 ORDER BY path
```

Тут мы собираем полный путь до конкретного элемента из всех промежуточных id и сортируем по нему. косая черта в пути введена для наглядности.

Если поле Id окажется переменной длины - то его надо будет явно привести к строке фиксированной длины с дополнением пробелами или нулями слева (`rigth('        '+Id,8)`)

Comment: По логике вроде должно сработать, но вот ms sql ругается, что нельзя преобразовывать UNIQUEIDENTIFIER к строке. "The data types varchar and uniqueidentifier are incompatible in the add operator."

Comment: Решилось похоже: WITH tree (Id, Name, Level, parents) AS (
      SELECT t.Id, t.Name, 0 AS Level,
             cast(t.id as varchar(max)) as parents
      FROM DepartmentsT t
      WHERE t.ParentId IS NULL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT d.Id, d.Name, Level+1,
             tree.parents + '-->' + cast(d.id as varchar(max)) as parents
      FROM DepartmentsT d INNER JOIN
           tree
           ON tree.Id = d.ParentId
    )
SELECT id, name, level
FROM tree
ORDER BY parents;

Comment: @temagr Она ругается на оператор сложения, потому что не может сложить строку и ваш идентификатор. приведите его явно к строке. `path+'/'+cast(d.Id as varchar)`