# Select Запрос из 2 таблиц с иерархией

Tags: sql, select

Народ, существует такое задание

```
·  A
     o B
          §  <doc1>
          §  <doc2>
     o C
          §  <doc3>
·  D
     o E
          §  F
          §  <doc5>
     o <doc4>
·  G
     o H
          §  I
                ·  <doc6>
```

Это дерево в бд 
Заглавные буквы это папки  это документы
стоит заметить что это 2 разные таблицы,

Таблица document

```
        ID NAME                       P_ID
---------- -------------------- ----------
         1 doc1                          2
         2 doc2                          2
         3 doc3                          3
         4 doc4                          4
         5 doc5                          5
         6 doc6                          8
```

Таблица folder

```
        ID NAME                       P_ID
---------- -------------------- ----------
         2 b                             1
         3 c                             1
         4 d                              
         5 e                             4
         6 f                             5
         7 g                              
         8 h                             7
         9 i                             8
```

Необходимо одним SELECT запросом выбрать все документы 2-го уровня, то есть уровня отмеченного § значком.
В выводе должны быть

```
doc1,doc2,doc3,doc5.
```

Заранее благодарю.

ВАЖНО!!! не должно быть рекурсии, разве что подзапросы select

Answer (score 0):

Сегодня уже мелькал подобный вопрос: [Выборка элементов 3 уровня в иерархии MySQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/634478/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-3-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B8-mysql)
Запрос по схеме из того топика:

```
SELECT    ds.document_id , ds.parent_id 
FROM folder_s l1  
inner JOIN folder_s l2 on l1.folder_id = l2.parent_id 
INNER JOIN document_s ds ON ds.parent_id = l2.folder_id 
where l1.parent_id = 1
```

запрошенный позже вариант через подзапросы:

```
SELECT ds.document_id , ds.parent_id
FROM document_s ds 
  where ds.parent_id IN (
SELECT 
  l2.folder_id
FROM folder_s l1 
inner JOIN  folder_s l2 on l1.folder_id = l2.parent_id
where l1.parent_id = 1
  )
```

Comment: а в лоб через SELECT в  SELECT е как сделать?