# Все sql запросы Nested Set

Tags: sql, nested-sets

Подскажите пожалуйста (работающие) sql запросы обновления ключей left_key и right_key при добавлении,удалении и перемещении узлов. Проще говоря хотелось бы разжеванной темы по Nested Set в MySQL. Хотелось бы увидеть как это делаете вы.

Comment: Практически хрестоматийная статья на эту тему - [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). Русскоязычная статья на Хабре, содержащая листинги полного комплекта готовых триггеров для работы с nested sets в PostgreSQL - [Nested Sets + PostgreSQL TRIGGER](https://habrahabr.ru/post/63416/). Обе они слишком объёмны, чтобы можно было привести в ответе сами листинги, а тем более пояснения к ним.

Comment: А есть какой аналог Nested Set ?

Comment: @webkostya "список смежности", он же наивное дерево. Есть ещё closure tree, он же materialized path, по сути то же что и closure tree, но со ссылками "наверх" не на один уровень непосредственно выше, а на каждый.

Comment: Уже не плохо ) А есть какой материал на тему "список смежности" ?

Comment: В принципе я понял что за "список смежности" , там в зависимости от глубины надо каждый раз добавлять новый join в запрос

Comment: @webkostya нет, там надо научиться CTE использовать.

Comment: @Mayorov Mayorov можно чуть подробней или ссылку ?

Comment: @webkostya Вы бы сказали какая у вас СУБД. Если MySQL то там дико неудобно работать с классическим деревом потомок-родитель так как нет рекурсивных запросов (хотя это обойти можно, но оно медленно и геморно). Практически все остальные СУБД поддерживают рекурсию и там с классическими деревьями работать просто

Comment: @Mike Да, у меня MySQL ) Расскажите как это можно обойти

Comment: @webkostya обойти ... простой способ - сменить СУБД, скажем на postresql. В MySQL простая задача по дереву превращается например в такое http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/634478 и что самое печальное, при небольшом изменении условий задачи может потребоваться изменять подход к решению. ну либо все таки использовать nested sets ... или ... не использовать в запросах обход дерева, а реализовать это на клиенте, что иногда удобно, если например делать подтягивание ветвей только по действию пользователя (при нажатии на [+] напротив узла дерева), в общем смотря по требуемым задачам ...

Comment: @Mike все понятно, спасибо )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Вставка:

```
exec("UPDATE Table SET R = R + 2 WHERE R >= ?", [$parent->r]);
exec("UPDATE Table SET L = L + 2 WHERE L >  ?", [$parent->r]);
exec("INSERT INTO Table (L, R, LEVEL ...) VALUES (?, ?, ?,...)", [$parent->r, $parent->r+1, $parent->level+1]);
```

### Удаление:

```
$d = $this->r - $this->l + 1;
$r = $this->r;
exec("DELETE FROM Table WHERE ID = ?", [$this->id]); // Foreign keys(pid->id) каскадом вычистят потомков
// если нет поля pid, можно `WHERE L>=? AND R<=?`
exec("UPDATE Table SET R = R - ? WHERE R > ?", [$d, $r]);
exec("UPDATE Table SET L = L - ? WHERE L > ?", [$d, $r]);
```

### Перемещение:

*Тут посложнее: (использован хак с отрицательными значениями `left/right` для временного выключения ветки)*

```
// Переносим ветку $this в родителя $parent
$d = $this->r - $this->l + 1;
// Прячем ветку, которую переносим
exec("UPDATE Table SET l = 0 - l, r = 0 - r WHERE l >= ? AND r <= ?", [$this->l, $this->r]);
exec("UPDATE Table SET l = l - ? WHERE l > ?", [$d, $this->r]);
exec("UPDATE Table SET r = r - ? WHERE r > ?", [$d, $this->r]);

// расширяем новое место
$pr = $parent->r > $this->r ? $parent->r - $d : $parent->r;
exec("UPDATE Table SET l = l + ? WHERE l >= ?", [$d, $pr]);
exec("UPDATE Table SET r = r + ? WHERE r >= ?", [$d, $pr]);

// Переносим спрятанную ветку на новое место
$pd = ($p->r > $this->r) ? $p->r - $this->r - 1 : $p->r - $this->r - 1 + $d; // Разница в r/l
$dl = $p->level + 1 - $this->level; // разница в уровнях
exec("UPDATE Table SET l = ? - l, r = ? - r, LEVEL = LEVEL + ? WHERE l <= 0-? AND r >= 0-?", [$pd, $pd, $dl, $this->l, $this->r]);
```

Сортировка элементов списка на одном уровне допиливается отдельно с помощью отдельного поля, т.к. не входит в идеологию `nested sets`

Comment: Какой странный у вас SQL...

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, будем считать, что это php-подобный псевдокод для `prepared statements`

Comment: У автора в тегах только SQL, весьма вероятно, что выполнять запросы он будет в консоли СУБД. Или сама СУБД будет выполнять их в триггерах.

Comment: Мне только SQL как раз и нужен был, автору спасибо, правда проверить пока нет возможности, вопрос решился, хоть и самым жестоким способом. А вообще думаю лучше всего просто перейти на PostgreSQL  и свободно пользоваться каскадными запросами

Comment: Этот ответ просто нельзя не принять ! ) Спасибо !