# PHP MySQL: Как посчитать количество родителей строки?

Tags: php, mysql

Таблица:

```
id | key  | name | parent
--------------------------
1  | 123  | 1'st | nothing
--------------------------
2  | 234  | 2'th | 123
--------------------------
3  | 345  | 3'rd | 234
--------------------------
4  | 456  | 4'th | 345
--------------------------
5  | 567  | 5'th | 123
```

И цикл:

```
if ($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `parent`='nothing'")) {
    if ($count = $result->num_rows) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
            $padding = 0;
            $comment_id = $row->id_key;
            $comment_name = $row->name;
            $comment_parent = $row->parent_key;
        }
    }
}
```

При каждом повторе цикла должна производится проверка количества родителей и их количество должно записываться в $padding, для удобного использование потом. Но также здесь есть ошибка в запросе, не выбраны все дети строки, я не знаю как это правильно сделать. Без выбора собсно детей нереально и бессмысленно проверять родителей.

Как это можно нормально организовать, ничего не меняя в таблице?

Comment: `$result->num_rows()` ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: *количества родителей и их количество должно записываться в $padding* Ну вообще-то это тупо уровень в дереве. А коли хранится дерево, обрабатывается как дерево - может, лучше хранить в структуре, специально предназначенной для хранения дерева?

Comment: @Akina нет, такая структура мне нравится и подходит больше всего. Самая простая и самая нормально выглядящая, в моем случае. Нужно только ее дополнить функционалом, перечисленным выше.

Comment: В таком случае предлагаю написАть нормальную рекурсивную хранимую процедуру, которая просчитает уровень для каждой записи и вернёт набор данных с уже посчитанным значением. И не надо огород городить, и будет в разы, а то и на порядок, эффективнее.

Comment: @KAYOver Я бы сказал что структура действительно хорошая (не считая, что корень обозначен "nothing", вместо значения NULL, которое предназначено как раз для таких случаев), вот только из всех распространенных SQL-СУБД вы к сожалению работаете с практически единственной, не поддерживающей рекурсивные запросы и не рассчитанной на работу с такими данными. так что вам надо либо писать рекурсивную функцию на php, которая будет ходить по родителям, либо оформлять то же в виде хранимой процедуры, либо сильно извращаться в запросе, примерно как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/634478/

Comment: @Mike nothing чисто здесь, чтоб понятно было. А так там вообще редко в каких случаях пустота.