# mysql запрос по древовидной структуре юзеров

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос, таблицы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Допустим есть такая древовидная таблица юзеров в mysql (столбец левел для примера, вообще он отсутствует), при этом id перемешаны. Как сделать запрос, чтоб выводил в таком порядке, как на картинке. Строго говоря, сначала берем первого человека в 1-ом поколении и выводим таким же образом всю его "глубину", потом 2-го и т.д.

Вот картинка, с порядком вывода юзеров.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Лучше этого не делать в MySQL потому что он совершенно на это не рассчитан. Если в БД предполагается хоть одна иерархическая структура лучше всего взять другую СУБД (почти любая другая подходит). Т.е. рекурсия конечно возможна, но она очень замысловата в реализации и при этом очень медленная, что то вроде этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/634545/194569

Comment: в постгресе это легко можно сделать с помощью WITH RECURSIVE. я так древовидную структуру подразделений организации выводил.