# Mysql выборка иерархии

Tags: mysql, sql

не могли бы вы помочь написать рекурсивный запрос на выбор данных из одной единственной таблицы ? (Без использования PHP)

Существует таблица

```
id, to_analog, to_brand, from_analog, from_brand, file.
```

для примера в таблице есть 6 строк.

```
111, бренд1, 222, бренд2
222, бренд2, 111, бренд1

222, бренд2, 333, бренд3
333, бренд3, 444, бренд4
444, бренд4, 555, бренд5
555, бренд5, 666, бренд6
666, бренд6, 777, бренд7
```

и т.д
В теории данные ссылаются друг на друга цепочкой.

```
111
  222
    333
      444
        555
          666
```

и т.д

Как можно составить запрос на получения данных имея например знания только об "111" или "333"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очень надеюсь, что у вас 8 версия mysql

Comment: Версия 10.1.37-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 Debian 9.6

Comment: Тогда вам не повезло. судя по relise notes эта версия Maria с функционалом MySQL 5.7 ... А это значит что придется извращаться как нибудь так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/634478/194569

Comment: Можно обновить, это не проблема) Мне главное  знать как это решить всё ?)

Comment: ну для текущей версии я показал. для родного MySQL 8 версии доступен рекурсивный CTE, который используется как то так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573758/194569 (можно искать по "Рекурсивный CTE")

Comment: *В теории данные ссылаются друг на друга цепочкой.* Только в теории. А на практике я не вижу никаких объяснений тому, что вторая запись `222, бренд2, 111, бренд1` тупо проигнорирована.